# Change my custom logo 'home destination' in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

header.php question here. I have a custom logo being used on a specific set of listings pages https://carolroyseteam.com/our-nice-home/ , I've assigned it using a body class assignment to swap the header $logo in the header.php. Then the rest of the site with the branding of the domain https://carolroyseteam.com/. Is there anything that can be done to assign a different url to the two $logo's?

To clarify my custom logo for Our Nice homes logo goes to '/our-nice-home/' and then have standard domain home logo link to the default logo cotainer ">

Using Divi Theme

```html
<?php ob_start(); ?>
  <header id="main-header" data-height-onload="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'menu_height', '66' ) ); ?>">
   <div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
   <?php
    $logo = ( $user_logo = et_get_option( 'divi_logo' ) ) && ! empty( $user_logo )
     ? $user_logo
     : $template_directory_uri . '/images/logo.png';

    ob_start();
   ?>
   <?php
    $classes = get_body_class();
if (in_array('ournicehomeslogo',$classes)) {
$logo="/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/1-ONH-Logo-05-carolroyseteam.png";}
    ?>
    
    <?php
    $classes = get_body_class();
if (in_array('single-listing',$classes)) {
$logo="/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/1-ONH-Logo-05-carolroyseteam.png";}
    ?>
    <?php
    $classes = get_body_class();
if (in_array('search-results',$classes)) {
$logo="/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/1-ONH-Logo-05-carolroyseteam.png";}
    ?>
    <div class="logo_container">
     <span class="logo_helper"></span>
     <a href="/our-nice-homes/">
      <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" id="logo" data-height-percentage="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'logo_height', '54' ) ); ?>" />
     </a>
    </div>
   <?php
    $logo_container = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Wordpress Divi Theme users will appreciate that this logo_container is a default in the header.php file. This has been the easiest way to both custom logo a specific page or pages and then modify the home url.

```html
<div class="logo_container">
     <span class="logo_helper"></span>
     <a href="<?php $classes = get_body_class(); 
          if (in_array('ournicehomeslogo',$classes)) {
echo esc_url( home_url( '/our-nice-homes/' ) );}

else if (in_array('single-listing',$classes)) {
echo esc_url( home_url( '/our-nice-homes/' ) );}

else if (in_array('search-results',$classes)) {
echo esc_url( home_url( '/our-nice-homes/' ) );}

else{
 echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
} ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" id="logo" data-height-percentage="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'logo_height', '54' ) ); ?>" />
     </a>
    </div>
   <?php
    
    $logo_container = ob_get_clean();
```